# An integer sequence defined from a variation of the Lucas–Lehmer primality test: the case of the Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, prime-factorization, totient-function

I did a variation of the so-called Lucas–Lehmer primality test,
 I say this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#The_test).  I've used the Euler's totient function
$$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\ p\text{ prime}}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p} \right)$$
for $n> 1$, and taking $\varphi(1)=1$ as definition. This is a well-known an important multiplicative function.

Our definition is $$\left.
\begin{array}{l}
E_i=\varphi(E_{i-1})E_{i-1}-2,\quad\text{for }i\geq 1\\
E_0=4
\end{array}
\right\}\tag{1}$$

From it, our sequence starts as $$4, 6, 10, 38, 682, 204598,20929966202\ldots\tag{2}$$

> **Question.** Please prove, provide heuristic, or refute the following conjecture:
>
> Conjecture-E: *One has that* $E_k$ is a square-free integer $\forall k\geq 1$.
>
> **Many thanks.**

That is, each term of our sequence $E_k$ has no repeated prime factors when $k\geq 1$. It seems that this sequences isn't in the OEIS.

Comment: If some user is interested maybe the case involving the sum of divisor function can be studied,

Comment: Many thanks @MichaelHardy

Comment: well... Sometimes I do substantial MathJax edits, but in this case I seem to have done the most trivial possible edit while deciding to leave the rest as it was, so maybe you exaggerate.

Comment: Okey... I've exaggerated $\checkmark$ @MichaelHardy

Comment: Wow, it sure isn't in the OEIS. I tried searching for just `4,6,10,38` and even that got no results.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @Mr.Brooks I think that the sequence isn't in the OEIS, nor another closely related sequence. If you are interested in this kind of recurences you can to study also the variation of the recurrence now using the sum of divisor function $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ instead of the Euler's totient; it is as a present for you